# Не понимаю ошибку в программе

Tags: python, python-3.x

Код вроде-бы исправный, что не так, не знаю. Вот ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 23, in <module>
NameError: name 'money' is not defined
```

Вот код:

```
class School:

 def __init__(self,money,pupils,averageCost,equipment):
  self.money = money
  self.pupils = pupils
  self.averageCost = averageCost
  self.equipment = equipment

def count(self,money,pupils,averageCost,equipment):
  x = 0
  while x > -1:
    x += 1
    self.money += averageCost * pupils
    self.equipment -= 1

  return self.money
  return self.pupils
  return self.averageCost
  return self.equipment 


  school_1 = School(10000,80,250,15000)
  school_1.count(money,pupils,averageCost,equipment)
```

Comment: переменные `money,pupils,averageCost,equipment` не объявлены и не инициализированы перед вызовом: `school_1.count(money,pupils,averageCost,equipment)`

Comment: @MaxU а как же __init__?

Comment: при вызове `school_1.count(money,pupils,averageCost,equipment)` вы обращаетесь к __внешним__ (не имеющим никакого отношения к переменным класса) переменным

Comment: @MaxU а как мне вызвать метод  __count__ корректно?

Comment: @Михаил а зачем метод `count` вообще принимает эти переменные? Он же может их получить через `self`, и в аргументах функции они абсолютно не нужны

Comment: @Михаил, никогда, ни за что не используйте 1 или 2 пробела для отступов. Ладно, используйте, но осторожно. Еще, у вас в коде проблемы с отступами, поэтому он не работает, поправьте пожалуйста. Еще, у вас ошибка из-за нескольких return'ов

Answer (score 2):

```
class School:

    def __init__(self,money,pupils,averageCost,equipment):
        self.money = money
        self.pupils = pupils
        self.averageCost = averageCost
        self.equipment = equipment

    def count():
        x = 0
        while x > -1:
           x += 1
           self.money += self.averageCost * self.pupils
           self.equipment -= 1

        return (self.money, self.pupils, self.averageCost, self.equipment) 

school_1 = School(10000,80,250,15000)
(money,pupils,averageCost,equipment) = school_1.count()
```

Исправил код за исключением одной, непонятной мне детали.

```
while x > -1:
    x += 1
```

Это бесконечный цикл, поправьте условие